# Getting wrong SSE response from the server

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, server-sent-events

Developing the project with Django. DRF installed.
Some processin the backend generating a log file. I am looking at the end of the file for target strings. When target string was caught, it has to be shown on HTML user page. Everything happens in dynamics.

urls.py

```
    path('api/log-stream/', LogStreamAPIView.as_view(), name='log_stream'),
```

LogStreamAPIView

```
class LogStreamAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        def stream_log():
            f = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', rcvenot_log], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            p = select.poll()
            p.register(f.stdout)

            while TEST_IN_PROGRESS:
                if p.poll(0.1):
                    new_line_log = f.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
                    for target_line in RCV_SCENARIO:
                        if target_line in new_line_log:
                            yield f"event: {new_line_log}\n\n"

        return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

Script on the user HTML page

```
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <ul id="logList"></ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var logList = document.getElementById('logList');

                function updateLog(newLine) {
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = newLine;
                    logList.appendChild(listItem);
                }

                var source = new EventSource('/api/log-stream/');
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    updateLog(event.data);
                };
            });
        </script>
```

I see the strigns via API `mysite.ru/api/log-stream/`. Some strings
`event: 2024.03.22 16:16:13:016[INFO ][Thread-0] ************************* - 2`

But I don't see them on HTML page.

In browser console I see the response code 406: `GET 127.0.0.1:8000/api/log-stream 406 (Not Acceptable)`
In Response see `{"detail":"The \"Accept\" request header could not be satisfied."}`

I have tried throw data in different formats `f"event: {new_line_log}\n\n"` or `f"data: {new_line_log}\n\n"`. It doesn't work.

Tried to add status in `return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_log(), content_type='text/event-stream’s , status=200)` and `status=202`. Same

Here is some screen shots of browser console.

[image: screen shots of browser console]

[image: screen shots of browser console]

Read the docs of SSE, the server should respond with `Content-Type: text/event-stream`, and in the browser console I see `Content-Type: application/json`. I suspect if the error might be a here...

Please help to figer out the problem

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because Django Rest Framework is trying to perform content negotiation. By default it looks at the `DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES` setting to figure out the possible content types it can return and if nothing matches it will return a 406 error.

Given this particular view of yours doesn't really seem to be using any DRF specific functionality one of your options is to simply convert that into a normal view that doesn't use DRF.

The other solution is to set up a [custom content negotiation class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation/#custom-content-negotiation) that simply ignores all of the content negotiation. Here's an example from DRF's documentation:

> ```py
> from rest_framework.negotiation import BaseContentNegotiation
>
> class IgnoreClientContentNegotiation(BaseContentNegotiation):
>     def select_parser(self, request, parsers):
>         """
>         Select the first parser in the `.parser_classes` list.
>         """
>         return parsers[0]
>
>     def select_renderer(self, request, renderers, format_suffix):
>         """
>         Select the first renderer in the `.renderer_classes` list.
>         """
>         return (renderers[0], renderers[0].media_type)
> ```

Then you'd modify your view to use this for content negotiation:

```
class LogStreamAPIView(APIView):
    content_negotiation_class = IgnoreClientContentNegotiation
    # Rest of your view
    ...
```

Comment: Thx a lot! With this (simply ignores all of the content negotiation) a got the response code 200 and in browser console in response see the correct data. But still the strings don't show up on user html page. Why does it can be?

Comment: I figered it out... Data must be send in format f"data: {data}\n\n". It's SSE requirement